# simplest non-trivial group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a textbook, I found an example for the simplest non-trivial group consisting of only 2 elements G={e,g} with $e$ being the neutral element.
The group is abelian and the Cayley table is given as

\begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
\cdot & e & g \\ \hline
 e & e & g \\ \hline
 g & g & e\\ \hline
\end{array}

I was wondering which kind of operator "$\cdot$ " can give rise to $g\cdot g=e$?

EDIT: Ok, got it. The table defines the operator. So $\cdot$ indeed corresponds to multiplication. 
I guess I was just looking for an example for an element $g$ being its own inverse.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've written the definition of "$\cdot$" yourself. Or perhaps I don't understand what "kind of operator" means?

Comment: Are you looking for a concrete, numerical example?  Because multiplication on $\{-1,1\}$ works.

Comment: It is not "what operator satisfy the table". The operator is *defined* by the table.

Comment: Matrix multiplication such that $e$ is the identity element and $g$ is any invertible matrix that is its own inverse (countless examples)

Comment: This is what the "abstract" in abstract algebra means.

Comment: Oh ok,  I see...the matrix multiplication hint made it clear. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While applying group theory (and other aspects of abstract algebra) can be concrete, in general we don't care much about what $e, g$ and $\cdot$ actually *are*. They are two elements and a multiplication, and how the multiplication works is defined by the table. Then when you come across a concrete example that works like this, you can think "Oh, I *know* this group" without ever having seen those exact objects before. This is the power of abstraction.

So you can ask about whether this group appears in any kind of concrete, not-too-farfetched setting, and that's a perfectly fine question to ask. Actually, having a *number* of different representations of each of the most common groups is a good way to spot connections between mathematical objects that isn't at first obvious.

In this case, you have $\{1, -1\}$ with regular multiplication. You have the set of linear isometries of a line with composition as the operation. You have the subset $\{0^\circ, 180^\circ\}$ of rotations of the plane (or of a circle), with composition as the operation. You have the set
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
of matrices with matrix multiplication. You have the additive group of integers modulo $2$. And loads of others.

That being said, don't be afraid of the purely abstract notion either, because at times it is going to be the only thing you have. And if you're not used to working with it at that point, it's going to be tough.

Comment: Thx for your nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, multiplication of $\{1, -1\}$ is an example. Then $\cdot$ is just ordinary multiplication. Another example would be $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is the integers modulo 2, where the operation is addition. The concept of involution deals with functions and operators that are their own inverse.

The point being that it is not always too important "what" the operation is  "what" the group is, as it can be many different things.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that you might like a physical example:

Consider a coin.  It may be laid on the table heads-up, or tails-up.  We can take two possible actions: Leave the coin laying on the table as is (i.e 'do nothing'), or flip it over.  Let us make a group out of these actions by the obvious product rule 'perform each action in succession'.  This clearly IS a group: (a) It is closed under product: Clearly 'do nothing' done before or after any other action is just that action, plus 'flip it over' twice is the same (i.e has the same result on the coin) as 'do nothing'; (b) It is associative: Doing the first action then the second (as one step), then a third, is trivially the same as doing the first action, then the second and third (as one step); c) There is an identity element ('do nothing'); d) Each action has an inverse (namely itself).

Answer (score 0):

Starting form linear algebra, the matrices $I_n$ and $-I_n$ generate a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ such that $e=I_n$ and $g=-I_n$. So we have a group of two elements. Of course, $g^2=(-I_n)^2=I_n=e$, but $g\neq e$.